# Copy constructors and inheritance

Tags: c++

I have three classes.

```
class A
{
private:
    int num;
//...
// THIS IS AN ABSTRACT CLASS (has a pure virtual function)
}

class B : public A
{
private:
    float fnum;
//...
}

class C : public A
{
private:
    double dnum;
    //...
}
```

Now, I have a function

```
foo(A& someA)
```

and in it I would like to initialize an `A*` object according to its' type (`B` or `C`). This `A` can be originally a `B` or a `C`

How can I do that using copy constructors? I have something like this:

```
A* newA = A.isB ? new B(someA) : new C(someA)
```

and I have added the copy constructors as such:

```
B(const B& b) : A(b) { fnum = b.fnum; }
C(const C& c) : A(c) { dnum = c.dnum; }
```

But this of course throws an error in the line

```
A* newA = A.isB ? new B(someA) : new C(someA)
```

that there is no suitable constructor.

Comment: Look at the prototype design pattern (e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns/Creational_Patterns#Prototype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is:

```
A* newA = A.isB ? new B(dynamic_cast<const B&>(someA)) : 
                  new C(dynamic_cast<const C&>(someA));
```

A cleaner solution is to declare:

```
virtual A* clone() const = 0;
```

in `A`, and then creating `newA` is just:

```
A* newA = someA.clone();
```

Each derived class, write:

```
A* B::clone() const {
    return new B(*this);
}
```

But **beware**: if you derive a class from `B`, you will need to reimplement `clone`, and the compiler won't warn if you don't.